# Putting blocking call inside a reactive chain seems to work in different thread

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Fairly new to reactor so please excuse if you don't see enough research or depth in the question.

In my reactive project, the resource API endpoint returns Mono. At one stage, I have to poll an external API to get a completion status, and use that status to process further, and ultimately construct the resource and return.

In another question, I asked if I could use `.repeatWhen()`, but it was just not working as I thought it would and user **@amanin** mentioned about `.retryWhen()`, about which I was initially apprehensive which is the reason why I tried `.repeatWhen()` in the beginning. `.retryWhen()` worked making desirable number of retry calls and stopping after that, so below is my adaptation of the `getStatus()` method.

```
public Mono<AppContext> getStatus(AppContext ctx) {
    externalclient.getStatus() // external API call, client returns Mono<Response>
    .map(resp -> {
        if(resp.isCompleted()) {
            ctx.setCompleted(true);
            return resp;
        }
        throw new RetryException();
    })
    .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(maxAttempts).filter(err -> err instanceof RetryException))
    .subscribe();
    return Mono.just(ctx);
}
```

Queries:

1. Is it the right approach because it looks like to me as an **anti-pattern** since I am controlling the flow with exception?
2. Above executes, but problem is my FTs seem to get the response while retries are still happening, meaning the main API thread and this retry thread are just not connected. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

With

```
externalclient.getStatus() // external API call, client returns 
// ...
.subscribe();
return Mono.just(ctx);
```

you immediately return `Mono.just(ctx)` that have nothing to do with external client call and all that logic. Do not call subscribe manually and return result of applying all that logic to the original Mono from external client like that:

```
public Mono<AppContext> getStatus(AppContext ctx) {
    return externalclient.getStatus() // external API call, client returns Mono<Response>
            .map(resp -> {
                if (resp.isCompleted()) {
                    return resp;
                }
                throw new RetryException();
            })
            .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(maxAttempts).filter(err -> err instanceof RetryException))
            .map(resp -> {
                        ctx.setCompleted(true);
                        return ctx;
                    }
            );
}
```

Subscribe would be done by spring-webflux under the hood.

The only controversial thing about controlling flow with exception for me is `instanceof`, because in general `retryWhen` is designed to handle Monos failed with exception. Imagine, for example, if there are a kind of network issue and `externalclient.getStatus()` returns Mono failed with exception raised under the hood. So may be you just don't need `.filter(err -> ...)` because you have to retry in case of any error.

Comment: I agree and it works. Thank you. But is that not an antipattern to handle the flow with exceptions? Is there a better approach to deal with this?

Comment: In general controlling flow by exception is considered as antipattern. In the particular case it seems relatively OK for me. At least I do not see a better solution. May be we even could consider it not as exception-flow-control. Think of that code that is definitely OK: `externalclient.getStatus().retryWhen()`. In case of network issue some exception would be thrown under the hood, and retryWhen would resubscribe. In case of non 2XX code some exception would (probably) be risen by client, catched by retry and that's OK. Treat raising an exception due to `!resp.isCompleted()` similar.

Comment: The whole lambda inside `map` could be a 3rd party method and eligible to throw any exception. And you are eligible to use `.retryWhen()`. The only concern for me is a custom exception and `.filter(err -> err instanceof RetryException)`. If you remove filter, then you get analog of `externalclient.getStatus().map(someFunction).retryWhen(Retry.backoff(maxAttempts))`. Looks good, isn't it?